# SQL: Using CASE to select certain elements from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one containing scores, the other containing a list of games.  Games have different types of highscores, such as a golfing game is judged by who has the lowest score.

I am trying to make a list of a certain user's high scores compared to the rest of the users (including games that consider high scores to be the lowest score.)

My old query was just assuming that all scores are the MAX score, but now I need to be able to check if the game's score type is "low".  I hear that using a CASE is able to solve this, but I'm running into a wall trying to reach the game table.

```
SELECT s.game_id, fp.score
FROM game_scores s
INNER JOIN games g ON s.game_id = g.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        CASE
          WHEN g.score_type = low THEN MIN(score)
          WHEN g.score_type = high THEN MAX(score)
        END as score, game_id
    FROM game_scores
    GROUP BY game_id
) fp ON s.game_id = fp.game_id AND s.score = fp.score
WHERE s.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    s.game_id, 
    CASE
        WHEN g.score_type = low  THEN MIN(s.score)
        WHEN g.score_type = high THEN MAX(s.score)
    END as score
FROM game_scores s
INNER JOIN games g ON s.game_id = g.id
WHERE s.user_id = 1
GROUP BY s.game_id, g.score_type
```

Comment: This is nice and clean! Thanks, this works for getting all of a certain user's high scores for each game.  I'll try to modify this so it only grabs their first place high scores compared to the rest of the users.

Comment: `SELECT s.game_id, ms.score, s.user_id FROM (SELECT ss.game_id, CASE WHEN gg.score_type = low THEN MIN(ss.score) WHEN gg.score_type = high THEN MAX(ss.score) END as score, s.user_id FROM game_scores ss INNER JOIN games gg ON ss.game_id = gg.id GROUP BY ss.game_id, gg.score_type) ms INNER JOIN game_scores s ON s.game_id = ms.game_id AND s.score = ms.score WHERE s.user_id = 1`

Comment: @pobrelkey you are amazing. Had 1 typo with calling s instead of ss. But perfect query! Thanks a lot for your time. I see my logic was off for this one haha.

Comment: @pobrelkey I am attempting to use your original answer for a query that pulls all the game's highest scores.  I took out the WHERE s.user_id = 1 line in order to grab all the scores site-wide with out any user restriction.  It seems to be getting all the correct high score numbers, but when I SELECT the score's USER_ID, it returns an incorrect ID of another user.  If i return the SCORE_ID, it also returns a score that does not match the correct highscore its returning.  I hope I wasn't confusing...

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused...  Have you tried `SELECT x.* FROM score x INNER JOIN ( /* my original query without the WHERE clause */ ) y ON x.game_id = y.game_id AND x.score = y.score`?

Comment: Well that did the trick. I swear I tried the same thing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to have a better answer, I'm post all code with my suggestion.

```
SELECT s.game_id, fp.score
  FROM game_scores s
       INNER JOIN games g ON s.game_id = g.id
       INNER JOIN (
           SELECT
               CASE
                 WHEN g.score_type = low 
                 THEN MIN(score)
                 ELSE MAX(score)
               END as score, 
               game_id
             FROM game_scores
           GROUP BY game_id
       ) fp 
            ON s.game_id = fp.game_id AND s.score = fp.score
    WHERE s.user_id = 1
```

Comment: But then fp still doesn't group by user_id.

Comment: My mistake - didn't understand the point of the OP (looking for a user's high scores that are high scores among all users, not just a list of one user's high scores).  Please make a trivial edit to your answer so I can remove the downvote.